# Android 2.1 programmatically unmount SDCard

Tags: android, linux, android-sdcard

I have an application that writes important data to the SDCard and encrypts it using AES, which later will be used by a desktop application. I have noticed that if I do not unmount the SDCard from the Settings menu sometimes the files don't get written at all, or are corrupted.

Is there anyway in Android 2.1 that I can unmount the SDCard programmatically? Because I'm pretty sure that from time to time the users will forget to do this, and I'll be the one fixing  the problems and I really don't want this.

If this is not possible,what Linux command should I use to unmount the SDCard? Since the application will run on some tablets that have a rooted OS.

Comment: Hi, i used the following lines but its not working for me,Is it really worked for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should unmount what's using the sdcard in the proper order, for example

```
umount /mnt/sdcard/.android_secure
umount /mnt/sdcard
```

or, probably synchronizing the buffers with the filesystem would be enough

```
sync; sync
```