# unmount sdcard programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, android-sdcard

1. I am working to implement Mount/Unmount sdcard support in my Android application, Am able to get sdcard state by `Environment.getExternalStorageState()`.I know we can call Settings Intent and Mount/Unmount, but my requirement has to do programmatically with out calling Settings Intent.
2. Is it possible to Enable/Disable the Settings application in Android?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7430149/android-2-1-programatically-unmount-sdcard.
You may need to root the device in order to do it.

Comment: i tried with Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_MEMORY_CARD_SETTINGS); startActivity(intent); but i want to handle Mount/Unmount sdcard through my activity, not from　settings application, because that is my requirement.Please any more advice?

Comment: @Kumar - Are you able to unmount the SDcard , pls do help me if you have solution How to unmount sdcard programatically.

Answer (score 2):

The settings app uses this permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />` See if you can use it.

Comment: Thanks for spending time for me, above permission useful for Allows mounting and unmounting file systems for removable storage.but here i want Mount/UnMount functionality same like in settings->storage-> Mount/UnMount sdcard fuctionality.

Comment: I found this http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/10b3ca563c118ccf